# UIButton like in UIActionSheet

Tags: objective-c

I would like put UIButton on my UIViewController with style like have buttons in UIActionSheet. What should i add here:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[ button setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 35) ];
[button setTitle:@"Button from UIActionSheet" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview: button];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the background image from somewhere and then set it using: `- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state`

I believe the .psd linked here has the action button background image http://media.photobucket.com/image/uiactionsheet%20button%20psd/visionwidget/iphone-gui-psd-file.jpg

Answer (score 1):

you can using segmented control - very good trick

```
segmented =  [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Info",@"Configuration", nil]] autorelease];
[segmented addTarget:self action:@selector(changeView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmented.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.20 green:0.20 blue:0.52 alpha:1.0];
segmented.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe exists some simple way like set some property?

Comment: Nope. If it isn’t in the documentation, you probably can’t do it out of the box.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/02/19/iphone-devsugar-create-shiny-buttons-easily/) is a post on using Apple's private UIGlassButton class.

You can't submit an app like this to the app store, but you *can* capture the generated background image to reuse in your published apps.